# Off-canvas search form from the top of the page

Tags: javascript, search, canvas, search-box, off-screen

I'm trying to do an off-canvas search form for a website. The input form should move down from the top (100% width) of the page pulling the rest of the contents down when the "search" button is clicked.

I'm not a pro in javascript so I searched on the web but didn't find anything, only off canvas menus that have different usages. I tried but it was too difficult for me to adapt them.

What are the steps to make it properly?

Here is the search form:

```
  <form method="get" action="<?php echo $PS ?>web/search.php">
            <label for="search"><?php echo t('search') ?></label>

            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />

            <button type="submit">&nbsp; <span class="visuallyhidden">Go</span></button>
         </form>
```

Any tips?
Thank you!

Comment: Example of what I need: https://www.cornell.edu/

Comment: Your question is unclear and your link is just the homepage of Cornell U (no help there). Please **BOTH** clarify what you want **and** post your existing code that is misbehaving (just posting the form code is not sufficient). Also, why tag this question with [canvas] -- it seems unrelated to [canvas]